# In which xaml controls you can draw

Tags: vb.net, uwp

I try my first app in uwp vb.net i want to draw a few polygones.
Which control to use ?
The target is to draw a timer which each part minutes seconds are shown with seven segment.In windows form i used a picture box 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> In which xaml controls you can draw

In UWP, we often use [Canvas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Canvas) to defines an area within which you can explicitly position child objects. You could use `Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes` to draw graph. It contains Line Ellipse and Rectangle etc. For more detail please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.shapes).